# Core data predicate on one-to-many relationship with contains

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate, magicalrecord

In my Core Data model, I have Conversation class, that has a 'participants' relationship, elements of which are instances of Participant class. Participant class has an href field that is a string.

Using MagicalRecord, I'm trying to fetch all Conversation instances that have at least one participant whose href contains '/businesses/%@', where %@ is a given identifier. In business terms, that means loading all the conversations in which a business with a given identifier is a participant.

Here is the code that is supposed to do the fetching:

```
NSPredicate *participationFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY participants.href contains[cd] '/businesses/%@'" argumentArray:@[identifier]];
NSArray *conversations = [Conversation MR_findAllWithPredicate:participationFilter];
```

But conversations is always empty, even though I know that such conversations are in my database. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the significance of using Magical Record ?

Comment: Magical Record is an open source framework to make Core Data easier to manipulate: https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord

Comment: Oh a Core Data wrapper.... not really my forte x.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'...'` in a predicate is taken as a literal string, and the `%@` placeholder inside the
quotation marks is not expanded. You have to build the combined string first:

```
NSString *searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/businesses/%@", identifier];
NSPredicate *participationFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY participants.href contains[cd] %@", searchTerm];
```